# How to identify a song from an audio file?

Tags: audio, music, search-engines

I heard part of a song in a video on Youtube. I can get that portion of the song in an audio file. I want to identify the song.

I did some research, there are some mobile applications that supposedly can identify songs from humming:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_by_humming

But I have found no workable program for PC or an on-line service.
I tried program called Tunatic, but it does not work.

What is the best free program for PC or a free on-line service that can identify a song from an audio file, containing some short portion of the song?

Comment: If you google your exact question title there are a few results advising that some sites can do it for free. Not a program, but at least online service.

Comment: [See this page](http://www.shazamforpc.org/shazam-pc-free-download/)

Comment: SoundHound on a phone - but it's still off-topic by a mile...

Comment: This is a great question, but should be posed on the Software Recommendations SE site.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys, I am still looking. I tried this one http://audiotag.info/ , but to no avail. This service said the audio was too short. This is the audio http://picosong.com/XkeD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that portion of the song, naming it sample from here on, contains lyrics then you can search for it on midomi, a web service for audio reverse search.

Things to note, I never got results on just instrumental samples, while on voice samples I mostly got good results, even on trance samples of obscure remix dj's, as long as it has some voices in it, it will increase chances by a lot of finding a good result.

To be able to use it with a sound sample on your computer you need to setup the recording device to not use mic, but the sound mixer. Then, any sound you play on the computer gets captured. Next you need to configure the browser to allow sound recording devices. And then you need to configure midomi's Flash player microphone. Click "Help" in page and "test your microphone" in the note that popped up. Right click on Flash and select Settings, something that's greyed out on the quick find "Click and Sing or Hum" flash app, and select the mixer as default mic.

Comment: Hi, emm980. Thanks for the answer. This is the sample http://picosong.com/XkeD . Not much of the lyrics. I will give midomi a try. Hope I will be able to figure out how to configure everything.

Comment: It was just enough... Leto Chili, or Chi-li Leto

Comment: Thanks a LOT, emm980! You are the man! Did you use midomi?

Comment: Of course, how else?

Comment: At first I thought you just knew the song. And then I tried midomi and it worked out! Not a very convenient way, though, but since there are no other workable suggestions, I am accepting your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: It's not convenient on first setup, but once it's done, it's easy to switch between default recording devices, play and search.